# how to Insert all datagrid rows in one time to sql data?

Tags: vb.net

i use this code in my project to save datagrid rows to sql database but it work if there is no more than one row ! because i want use it in (Sales invoice form)
What change do I need ?

```
        ' in datagrid this code save one row only


    Dim SaveCmd1 As SqlCommand = Zsqlcon.CreateCommand()
    SaveCmd1.CommandText = ("insert into InvoicesDbTb2(IteSName,IteSSizeUnit,IteSCont,IteSPri,IteSTotContPri,IteSTask,IteSTotlAmnt) values 
                                   (@IteSName,@IteSSizeUnit,@IteSCont,@IteSPri,@IteSTotContPri,@IteSTask,@IteSTotlAmnt)")

    For i As Integer = 0 To SellingDGView.Rows.Count - 2
        Dim unused = SaveCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IteSName", SellingDGView.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString())
        Dim unused3 = SaveCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IteSSizeUnit", SellingDGView.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString())
        Dim unused4 = SaveCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IteSCont", SellingDGView.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value.ToString())
        Dim unused5 = SaveCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IteSPri", SellingDGView.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value.ToString())
        Dim unused6 = SaveCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IteSTotContPri", SellingDGView.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value.ToString())
        Dim unused7 = SaveCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IteSTask", SellingDGView.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value.ToString())
        Dim unused8 = SaveCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IteSTotlAmnt", SellingDGView.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value.ToString())

    Next
```

Comment: Consider working off a DataSource for the DataGridView rather than working from DataGridView cells, the data source might be a DataTable or a List(Of T) then work the inserts in a class method. This can be Oracle, Access, SQL-Server etc. See a MS-Access version [here](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/WorkingWithAccessDatabases/blob/master/AddingMultipleRecords/Classes/DataOperations.vb#L55)

Comment: thanks for your comment & help.  i tried but its not working with me !

Comment: In regards to "not working for me", that is too broad of a response, you need to be specific. In the mean time learn to use the debugger and check the results of ExecuteNonQuery. Also how are you verifying this is not working? You can edit your question and post revised code along with what type of database is being used. Lastly if this is Access and the database is in the project make sure Copy to output folder under properties is set to Copy if newer. If SQL-Server make sure you are targeting the right db.

Comment: My database is running in SQL-Server. And the code makes it clear it's an Sql not OleDb. I believe that all I need is a simple edit that makes the code save all rows instead of one.

Comment: For SQL-Server OleDbConnection becomes SqlConnection, OleDbCommand becomes SqlCommand e.g. [see the following](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/MoveFromAccessToSqlServerWithVisualBasicNet/blob/master/BasicInsertNewRecord/Classes/DataOperationsSqlServer.vb#L26)

Comment: ok i will try it.

Comment: I checked the code you provided and it brought me no help whatsover, because it contains stuff that are not in my own project. Because of that, thanks for your help and there is no way to find my answer here. I'll try checking elsewhere.

Comment: Sorry to hear you are not willing to take a chance and expand what's in your project. Good luck.

Comment: Sure, I will expand, and I am doing that step by step but in the mean time all I nead is an answer for this to move on! Because that answer would allow me to understand the workings of this system.

Comment: Inserting data is pretty much exactly the same as editing data. To edit existing data, create a `DataTable`, call `Fill` on a `SqlDataAdapter` to populate it, bind it to the `DataGridView`, edit as required then call `Update` on the data adapter to save the changes. For inserting data, the only thing that changes is that you call `FillSchema` instead of `Fill` to create the schema in the `DataTable` without retrieving any existing data. There are plenty of examples of this sort of thing on the web and you've shown no indication of doing any of that.

Comment: you could also try SqlBulkUpload fetatures

Answer (score 0):

You need to include part of the sql command building inside the loop.

P.S, although I’m not going to check for them here, there are limits on how many parameters and how long the sql command text can b (~2000 and ~8k respectively).

```
    ' in datagrid this code save one row only


Dim SaveCmd1 As SqlCommand = Zsqlcon.CreateCommand()
Dim sb as new StringBuilder
Sb.appendLine("insert into InvoicesDbTb2(IteSName,IteSSizeUnit,IteSCont,IteSPri,IteSTotContPri,IteSTask,IteSTotlAmnt) values ")


For i As Integer = 0 To SellingDGView.Rows.Count - 2
 Sb.appendLine($"(@IteSName{i},@IteSSizeUnit{i},@IteSCont{i},@IteSPri{i},@IteSTotContPri{i},@IteSTask{i},@IteSTotlAmnt{i}){if(I=SellingDGView.Rows.Count - 2,"",",")}")
    Dim unused = SaveCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@IteSName{i}", SellingDGView.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString())
    Dim unused3 = SaveCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@IteSSizeUnit{i}", SellingDGView.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString())
    Dim unused4 = SaveCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@IteSCont{i}",  SellingDGView.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value.ToString())
    Dim unused5 = SaveCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@IteSPri{i}", SellingDGView.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value.ToString())
    Dim unused6 = SaveCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@IteSTotContPri{i}", SellingDGView.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value.ToString())
    Dim unused7 = SaveCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@IteSTask{i}", SellingDGView.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value.ToString())
    Dim unused8 = SaveCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@IteSTotlAmnt{i}", SellingDGView.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value.ToString())

Next
SaveCmd1.CommandText= sb.ToString
```

Another way to solve your problem is to do the insert inside the loop.  While this will be slightly slower, in practice the difference is going to be irrelevant at your scale.  If it was relevant, your entire process would need to be changed drastically.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To SellingDGView.Rows.Count - 2
  Dim sb as new StringBuilder
Sb.appendLine("insert into InvoicesDbTb2(IteSName,IteSSizeUnit,IteSCont,IteSPri,IteSTotContPri,IteSTask,IteSTotlAmnt) values ")
 Sb.appendLine($"(@IteSName{i},@IteSSizeUnit{i},@IteSCont{i},@IteSPri{i},@IteSTotContPri{i},@IteSTask{i},@IteSTotlAmnt{i})")

    Using SaveCmd1 = Zsqlcon.CreateCommand(Sb.ToString)

    Dim unused = SaveCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@IteSName{i}", SellingDGView.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString())
    Dim unused3 = SaveCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@IteSSizeUnit{i}", SellingDGView.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString())
    Dim unused4 = SaveCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@IteSCont{i}",  SellingDGView.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value.ToString())
    Dim unused5 = SaveCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@IteSPri{i}", SellingDGView.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value.ToString())
    Dim unused6 = SaveCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@IteSTotContPri{i}", SellingDGView.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value.ToString())
    Dim unused7 = SaveCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@IteSTask{i}", SellingDGView.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value.ToString())
    Dim unused8 = SaveCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@IteSTotlAmnt{i}", SellingDGView.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value.ToString())

    SaveCmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
  End Using

Next
```

Comment: Mr. jmoreno it wouldn't be enough to thank you for what you helped me in. All what you did has pointed me toward the right direction. and thank you for your great help.

Comment: I think this would be inefficient. Sql Server can cache execution plans. If you set up your complete command and add the parameters outside the loop, then you only need to change the values of the parameters inside the loop. Sql Server can then reuse the query plan.

Comment: Please don't use .AddWithValue. See http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
and
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/
and another one:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications
Here is another
https://andrevdm.blogspot.com/2010/12/parameterised-queriesdont-use.html

Comment: If you're saying not to use .AddWithValue, can you also tell me the alternative? This doesn't help. Or can you at least edit my code and make it right, so I could understand better?

Comment: Mary ... do you mean change it to this change for example (Dim unused1 = SaveCmd1.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter($"@IteSName{i}", SellingDGView.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString()))) ?

Comment: @Mary: both the query plan (this is an insert) and the problems with AddWithValue are general problems that aren’t relevant for this particular example.

Comment: @ZaerAllail See my Answer for how to use .Add

Answer (score 0):

Keep you connection and command local to the method where they are used. These database objects may be used unmanaged resources which need to be released. Normally this is done in their .Dispose method. A `Using...End Using` block handles this for you even if there is an error.

Add the parameters once outside the loop. I had to guess at the datatypes. **Check your database for the actual types** and adjust the code accordingly. You will also have to adjust the values of the parameters in the loop. See the `CInt`, `CDec`, `.ToString` etc..

Only the values of the parameters change in the loop. You are not creating and adding the parameters over and over.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Using Zsqlcon As New SqlConnection("Your connection string"),
     SaveCmd1 As New SqlCommand("insert into InvoicesDbTb2(IteSName,IteSSizeUnit,IteSCont,IteSPri,IteSTotContPri,IteSTask,IteSTotlAmnt) values 
                               (@IteSName,@IteSSizeUnit,@IteSCont,@IteSPri,@IteSTotContPri,@IteSTask,@IteSTotlAmnt)", Zsqlcon)
        With SaveCmd1.Parameters
            .Add("@IteSName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100)
            .Add("@IteSSizeUnit", SqlDbType.Int)
            .Add("@IteSCont", SqlDbType.Int, 100)
            .Add("@IteSPri", SqlDbType.Decimal)
            .Add("@IteSTotContPri", SqlDbType.Decimal)
            .Add("@IteSTask", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100)
            .Add("@IteSTotlAmnt", SqlDbType.Decimal)
        End With
        Zsqlcon.Open()
        For i As Integer = 0 To SellingDGView.Rows.Count - 2
            With SaveCmd1
                .Parameters("@IteSName").Value = SellingDGView.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString()
                .Parameters("@IteSSizeUnit").Value = CInt(SellingDGView.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value)
                .Parameters("@IteSCont").Value = CInt(SellingDGView.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value)
                .Parameters("@IteSPri").Value = CDec(SellingDGView.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value)
                .Parameters("@IteSTotContPri").Value = CDec(SellingDGView.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value)
                .Parameters("@IteSTask").Value = SellingDGView.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value.ToString()
                .Parameters("@IteSTotlAmnt").Value = CDec(SellingDGView.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value)
            End With
            SaveCmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Great Job @Mary. The Code system Works Well For Me And Understandably. And Believe Me This Is What I'm Asking For.  And Both answers (@jmoreno,@Mary) are helpful to me.Thanks For you Both.

Comment: Can You Explain To Me Please ...
Why Some Of The Lines In The Parameter Section Have Been Converted to strang like Decimal and Int and Some Lines Have Not Been Converted ?

Comment: @ZaerAllail The datatypes of the parameters (`SqlDbType`) will match the types of the columns of the table in the database. When you assign data to the `.Value` of the parameters you want to be sure that the types will be accepted by the database. If the parameter is `SqlDbType.Int` then we use `CInt` on the data being assigned to that parameter.

Comment: Can't Imagine How Far The Answers To This Question Were Useful To Me. thanks @Mary I Got It.